# urca R Package: How to create latex output for Johansen results?

Tags: r

I am using the package `urca` for GNU R to do some cointegration analysis with the Johansen method. While the actual analysis works quite well, I am having trouble getting the results of the cointegrated model into LaTeX tables to properly document the results.

### How to export the estimated VECM from urca package into a LaTeX table?

What works: The information I get when I run the `summary` on the VECM returned by URCA essentially returns what I want to have in the table. However, extracting it manually is a pain - and I was not able to find the standard errors in the `cajorls`.

The code to see my problem

```
test <- data.frame( a = cumsum(runif(500)) + runif(500))
test$b <- test$a + runif(500);
summary(cajorls(ca.jo(test))$rlm)
# i want the info displayed on screen here to go to a latex table
```

Sample output on screen: includes standard errors and p-values -

```
> summary(cajorls(ca.jo(test))$rlm)
Response a.d :

Call:
lm(formula = a.d ~ ect1 + constant + a.dl1 + b.dl1 - 1, data = data.mat)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.26742 -0.29212 -0.00504  0.29866  1.29933 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
ect1     -0.01465    0.10661  -0.137    0.891    
constant  0.65066    0.06231  10.443  < 2e-16 ***
a.dl1    -0.37889    0.08852  -4.280 2.24e-05 ***
b.dl1     0.05575    0.07497   0.744    0.457    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4806 on 494 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.545, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5413 
F-statistic: 147.9 on 4 and 494 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

### Ideal solution to get VECM exported as latex table

My ideal solution would allow me to use an existing package like `stargazer` and add custom statistics (e.g. autocorrelation) to the output.

Solution can require installation of an external package or include custom code.

Comment: `summary(cajorls(ca.jo(test))$rlm)` is a list of objects of class `summary.lm`, with one per series; they should contain all the statistics you are looking for (in particular, the coefficients and their standard errors are under `coefficients`). You can use this information to build whatever tables you want, I'm not sure which packages are most helpful here.

Comment: @ChrisHaug many thanks for this pointer, I am about to post my complete solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cajorls` method returns a list of `summary.lm` objects, as pointed out in the comment above. It does not return the `lm` object, which is what makes creating tables hard; for example, stargazer is hard to adapt for dealing with the summary object. However, another CRAN package - called `texreg` [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/) - gets the job done relatively easily.

This needs two steps:

### Extend `texreg` to handle `summary.lm` objects

As of writing, `texreg` cannot natively work with summary objects; instead, it wants the `lm` object (like stargazer) - although almost all of the information is then taken from the summary object. Thankfully, it is quite easy to work around this limitation. Just copy and paste the code from the related Github issue: [Workaround: How to render summary.lm objects using texreg](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/issues/52)

### Render the table

```
 > mysum <- summary(cajorls(ca.jo(test))$rlm)
 > screenreg(list(mysum[[1]], mysum[[2]]))

 =================================
            Model 1     Model 2   
 ---------------------------------
 ect1         0.14        1.18 ***
             (0.10)      (0.12)   
 constant     0.74 ***    1.27 ***
             (0.06)      (0.07)   
 a.dl1       -0.35 ***    0.66 ***
             (0.08)      (0.09)   
 b.dl1       -0.01       -1.04 ***
             (0.07)      (0.08)   
 ---------------------------------
 R^2          0.56        0.56    
 Adj. R^2     0.55        0.55    
 Num. obs.  498         498       
 RMSE         0.47        0.54    
 =================================
 *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

### Bonus: Adding Custom Test Statistics of the VECM to texreg latex table

`texreg` allows us to simple add goodness-of-fit measures to the "extracted" model summary. Upside: fast and easy. Downside: no stars for significance.

As an example, let's add the p-value of the Shapiro test for normality of the residuals:

```
 mm <- lapply(mysum, function(mod) {
   tr <- extract(mod)
   tr@gof <- c(tr@gof, shapiro.test(mod$residuals)$p.value);
   tr@gof.names <- c(tr@gof.names, "Shapiro Test")
   tr@gof.decimal <- c(tr@gof.decimal, TRUE);
   return(tr)
 })
 screenreg(mm);
```

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful solution. Should "Model 1", "Model 2" be "a.d" and "b.d" respectively? If so, how can I modify the names of the columns?

Comment: You will need to add a parameter to screenreg/texreg, like so `custom.model.names = c("a.d","b.d")`!